# How do I change the format of a value in a table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table that displays the following values:

```
const COLS = [
  { value: "NumCheck", displayName: '#Check' },
  { value: "Date", displayName: 'Date' },
  { value: "Obj", displayName: 'Object' },
  { value: "Sum", displayName: 'Sum' }
];
```

And I want the `Sum` value to be displayed in this format `#.00`.

How can this be done if I have such a table?

```
     <table mat-table class="tb" [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column.value" *ngFor="let column of allCols;">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                    {{column.displayName}}
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                    {{column.value === 'Date' ? (row[column.value] | date  : 'dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm'): row[column.value]}}
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **number** **pipe**

```
{{column.value === 'Date' ? (row[column.value] | date  : 'dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm'): ((column.value === 'Sum') ? (row[column.value] | number:'.2-2'):row[column.value])}}
```

Comment: `Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ':' at column 157 in' Error: Unexpected token ':' at column 157 in [ {{column.value === 'Date' ? (row[column.value] | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm') : (column.value === 'Sum'?(row[column.value] | number:'.2-2') : row[column.value]) : row[column.value]}} ] in`

Comment: Angular switch case attribute can be used,

Answer (score 0):

`Angular` **switch case attribute** can be used, just like the example below, the parameter sent can be formatted according to the type of data.
I use `Colums.ts`
I use a columns entity of **propertytype**, this way I can format it according to which parameter type.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column.key" *ngFor="let column of columns">
        <th mat-header-cell cdkDrag *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="{{ column.key }}">
            {{ column.columnName }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let col">
            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="column.propertyType">
                <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'Date'">
                    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="dateTemp"></ng-container>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'Number'">
                    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="numberTemp"></ng-container>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'String'">
                    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stringTemp"></ng-container>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-template #dateTemp>
                    {{col[column.key] | date  : 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template #numberTemp>
                    {{col[column.key] | number}}
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template #stringTemp>
                    {{col[column.key]}}
                </ng-template>
                <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
                    ...
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

**for example propertytype**

1. Date
2. Number
3. String
4. Other